# unauthorized remote access

Tags: remote-access, pci

I continue to be harassed by unauthorized remote access of my computers, even though I have done everything NOT to be on the internet.  I just located sone files indicating that I have the following hardware I did not know I had: "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B20 and others.  Can these devices be used to for remote access?  I found this on a new computer I had built with express instructions that it was not to have any wireless capabilities.  My limited research suggests I my have been duped.  Is this actual hardware that can be seen?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware you mention - PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B20 - is part of an Intel chipset, namely the 4-port Serial ATA controller that is most likely on your motherboard. If you want to see the actual interface hardware on your system, run `lspci` in Terminal.

To make any effort to see if you are being probed/attacked, you would need to provide information from your system logs (/var/log/syslog, /var/log/auth.log) that you believe are suspicious activity for us to provide any insights.

Ubuntu, like most flavors of Linux, is very secure until you start enabling services (mail, Apache, SSH, etc.) and opening their ports to the wilds of the Interwebs.